# Dockerfile folder permission

Tags: dockerfile, laravel-8, amazon-ecs

I am running a Dockerfile for a Laravel project where I need to change the permission to the folder ./storage/* to 777, using entrypoint.sh with commands. But inside the container the folder permissions are still 755. I don't get any error messages. Everything else goes smooth.

Deployment process:

- Github actions build, test, deploy
- Push to AWS ECR
- Deploy with AWS ECS
- Server AWS EC2

**DOCKERFILE**

```
FROM ***
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential libpng-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libfreetype6-dev locales zip jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle unzip git libonig-dev curl
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www/html
COPY docker/apache/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN docker-php-ext-install mbstring pdo pdo_mysql && a2enmod rewrite negotiation
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer
RUN composer require laravel/sail --dev

ENV APP_ENV="local"
ENV DB_CONNECTION="mysql"
ENV DB_HOST="18.135.244.213"
ENV DB_PORT="3306"
ENV DB_DATABASE="test-db"
ENV DB_USERNAME="admin"
ARG DB_PASSWORD
ENV DB_PASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD
RUN ["php","artisan","migrate:refresh","--seed"]
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
COPY ./docker/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 80
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# Set the ownership and permissions for the storage folder
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/storage
chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/storage

# Start the supervisor
exec /usr/bin/supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
```

Can anyone explain why the folder permissions are not changing?

I have tried basically everything within my knowledge without any any results.

Comment: You aren't overriding the entrypoint when you run the container are you? Why not just have those `chown` and `chmod` commands inside the Dockerfile instead of in the entrypoint script?

Comment: Because I thought the entrypoint file is executed when the container is started.

Comment: It is, if you don't override the entrypoint when you run the container. But why make it take the time to do that stuff every time the container is started, instead of doing it once, when you build the docker image?

Comment: Okay, good point. But we seem to have found the problem with ECS deployment, so it was not Dockerfile problem at all. But thank you for the tips, I really appreciate.

Comment: If there is a problem with ECS that caused this, please post the answer so the rest of us will know.